# Breakpoint Line Numbers in VB Editor

Tags: vba, breakpoints, line-numbers, extensibility, vbe

Does anyone know how to get line numbers of breakpoints in the VB Editor programmatically? I can't find a way to do this currently with the VBA Extensibility Library (Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3).

FYI, I've already numbered my lines (starting with 10 and increasing by 10 for each line, excluding `Dim`'s)

Comment: Can you confirm you're talking about "Visual Basic for Applications" - (e.g. the VBA editor in Microsoft Office?), if so, which host-application are you using?

Comment: Yes, Visual Basic for Applications (VBA). I'm using Excel 2016. I'd like to pull the line numbers where programmer has put breakpoints (not `Stop` statements in the code, but specifically breakpoints signaled by the red circles)

Comment: I am pretty sure that you will need to create an Excel VSTO Add-in project in Visual Studio. [MZ Tools Trail](https://www.mztools.com/v8/download_trial.aspx) cost  $64, but it has a lot f useful features.  Including line numbering .  [VBA Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) is also feature packed for the low low price of free.

Comment: Why would you need to the breakpoint numbers?

Comment: Just for logging different testing for personal reasons. Ultimately, I'd like to program the Margin Indicator Bar if I could. I have `Rubberduck` and `MZ Tools`, but they do not provide this functionality. I'm wondering if I can program the Margin Indicator Bar in VBA or if I have to write a COM Add-In in another language.

Comment: Looking into this, it does look like I'd have to write a VSTO Add-In. Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there a language reference for the Margin Indicator Bar?